# Import viewController from project to library in swift/objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, reusability

I have some reusability modules/tabs for my application. I added libraries by Cocoapods. I have "Common" module where it contains common elements for all tabs, but sometimes requires a lot of dependent imports.

[image: Xcode]

It's possible to `ExampleViewController` import from "MyApp" to another library for example Wall? I usually imports from "Common".

Why `#import <MyApp/ExampleViewController-Swift.h>` isn't working?

Below is my calling function to this ViewController. How to use bundle?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see there no answers. I found it myself.

If someone has a similar situation. The answer is `NSNotificationCenter`.

Add to your function where you want open `SettingsViewController`:

```
@IBAction func userPhotoClicked(_ sender: Any) {
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("profileSide"), object: nil) }
```

and on this ViewController (was written in Objective-c) where the action add observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(profileSide:) name:@"profileSide" object:nil];
```

and remove observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"profileSide" object:nil];
```

and write function "profileSide" on this same view controller where you have AddObserver and RemoveObserver.

```
- (void)profileSide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    SettingsViewController *vc = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

All the best.